# How to delete all emails older than a certain date in gmail?

Tags: gmail

Suppose I want to delete all emails older than year 2012 in gmail. Currently, what I do is put `Before: 2012` in the search box. However using this method, I have to delete the emails 100 conversations at a time. This is time-consuming and tiring on my finger muscles. How can I delete all emails older than year 2012 in gmail in one stroke?

EDIT: The answer in the possible duplicate no longer works. I am no longer able to select all conversations. Emails have to be selected and deleted 100 conversations at a time.

Comment: Once you select all the conversations a message is showed on the top with a link to select all the mails. This is already on the possible duplicate. Related: [How do I delete all my mail from my Gmail account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2/88163) and [Why doesn't my Gmail account have the “select all” option?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29282/88163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like you did before: put `Before:2012` in the search box, select all messages using the checkbox at the top left. And then look at the top of messages (below Gmail toolbar), there should be the following message:
All 100 conversations on this page are selected. Select all conversations that match this search  
 
[image]
Click the link.

Comment: Something is not right with gmail. I did as follows. Gmail even says all conversations deleted. However, in the trash folder, nothing appears. I have to delete the conversations 100 at a time to transfer the conversations to trash folder.

Comment: did you click "delete" immediately or clicked through pages? And you should wait some time before the process is done.

Comment: I did wait. Gmail even warned me that all conversations will be affected. Strangely, none of the conversations were affected after I confirm.

Comment: Yeah, just having the UI for the functionality being there doesn't answer the question if said UI doesn't actually work.